# com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices! error on Jenkins

Tags: android, unit-testing, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have Jenkins 2.73.1 installed on my Windows 7 machine, with no slaves.  There is a single job to build an android application setup.  I have the `connectedCheck` gradle task exected as part of the job's build process.

When I restart my computer and run my Jenkins job I see this output:

```
23:15:46 :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
23:15:46 Starting 166 tests on Nexus_5X_API_26(AVD) - 8.0.0
23:15:48 
23:15:48 (packages).(testclass) > testMethod[Nexus_5X_API_26(AVD) - 8.0.0] [31mFAILED [0m
23:15:48    java.lang.AssertionError
23:15:48    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)

23:15:49 There were failing tests. See the report at: file:(path to app) /app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html
```

This is totally expected - I have a failing test in place to 'test' Jenkins out!

However I often run into the following issue after 'using' the same machine to do  development work (it's shared with Jenkins - I know, 100% wrong to have development and Jenkins side by side, but this is for me to learn about Jenkins really, not to have it 100% safe if at all possible, I fully understand the answer may be to isolate dev/jenkins, but maybe there are other solutions for now?).  I run the simulator, unit tests, etc. and eventually Jenkins complains:

```
00:27:19 :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
00:27:19 
00:27:19 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
00:27:19 
00:27:19 * What went wrong:
00:27:19 Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
00:27:19 > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
00:27:19 
00:27:19 * Try:
00:27:19 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
00:27:19 
00:27:19 BUILD FAILED
00:27:19 
00:27:19 Total time: 1 mins 1.687 secs
00:27:20 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
00:27:20 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
00:27:20 [android] Stopping Android emulator
00:27:23 [android] Archiving emulator log
00:27:23 $ D:\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe kill-server
```

I absolutely have the simulator running as part of the job - I'm not sure what's going on.  Any thoughts?

EDIT: I am using the Android Emulator plugin 2.15 to setup my emulator during the job.  It is setup using an existing emulator name.  In the logs I do see it start successfully each time, and also logs stating that it is stopping the simulator/etc after the job is finished (see the logs above i.e. "[android] Stopping Android emulator" etc.)

Comment: Are you using this plugin ? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin

Comment: Yes.  I am using an existing emulator via the plugin.

Comment: Oh now i remember. @Zach, i can able to run only once emulator from jenkins.  Then restart your windows and you able to run again. It seems emulator from jenkings can't able to stop existing emulator before it creating again. I also still can't able to find any solutions even after i tried to find out so many group/discussions.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but my devops team is facing this same issue now. Can you please post the solution if you were able to find one. Thanks