# Gradle - Jacoco to only execute unit test without throwing device not found exception

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I am trying to execute only unit test and genrate jacoco test report, but I see always a failure message saying

```
Execution failed for task ':App:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

Gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.1"
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testTpsDebugUnitTest', 'create<build-vairant>DebugCoverageReport']) { 
    group = "reporting"
    description = "Generate unified Jacoco code coverage report"

    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination  file("${buildDir}/reports/jacocoHtml")
    }

    def fileFilter = [
            '**/*Test*',
            '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
            '**/*_Factory.class']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/<build-variant>/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/test<build-variant>DebugUnitTest.exec"
    ])
```

I execute with command:

```
 ./gradlew -Pcoverage clean jacocoTestReport
```

Please help to fix this issue, so it only executes unit test and doesnt ask for a device!

Comment: You'll need to have an Android Emulator running or a physical device connected and in usb debugging mode.

See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#preparing-the-android-device for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039119/com-android-builder-testing-api-deviceexception-no-connected-devices)

Comment: Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398159/com-android-builder-testing-api-deviceexception-no-connected-devices-error-on?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, it worked when I removed "'create<build-vairant>DebugCoverageReport'"

Comment: If the project only has Unit Tests, then a device should not be required.  To prove this you can easily run the Unit Tests with not device at all (JUnit 5).  There's something wrong with Jacoco--it always seems to run AndroidTests, not Unit Tests.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue while debugging my Jacoco installation, and fortunately for me it was the beginning of the solution.

If you are running Unit Tests (including Jacoco Unit tests), a device should not be needed.  AndroidTests require a device, not Unit Tests.

After installing all the Jacoco changes to the gradle and re-synced:

1. Open the gradle window of Android Studio (View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle) you will see an icon of an elephant (as of Android Studio Chipmunk)[image].
2. Click on this icon and a command window will appear. [image]
3. Type in the box as shown: `gradle app:createDebugUnitTestCoverageReport` and hit .

This will start the Jacoco process running.  Since it generally relies on Unit Tests (assuming your gradle is configured correctly), it will force the Unit Tests to run first.  You'll find your report in the location you specified in the gradle (default is something like ./app/build/reports/coverage/test/debug/index.html).

My problem was I was entering the wrong unit test in step 3.  I typed `gradle app:createDebug...` and accepted the first suggestion.  This was *wrong*!  It put `createDebugAndroidTestUnitCoverageReport`, which was *not* what I wanted (and caused the error requesting a device).